# Sending an MMS programatically to Metro PCS MMSC (via Nokia Implementation)

Tags: android, nokia, mms

This is my first post so my apologies in advance if this is the wrong site to post this particular question to.

**Question**
I have integrated Nokia's MMS implementation for android (http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-send-mms-programmatically-in.html) into an android application I am writing and I am able to send MMS's from my personal Metro PCS device to Metro PCS's MMSC and messages are delivered to any recipient without issue.

This is how I am sending the MMS:

```
   public Boolean sendMMSMessage(final String senderNumber, final String smsText, final File imageFile, final Integer requestId){
       byte[] out;
       Enumeration keys;
       //set image File 
       setImageFile(imageFile);
       //create MMMessage
       setMMMessage(new MMMessage());
       //add text
       addText(getMMMessage(),smsText,"<0>",IMMConstants.CT_TEXT_PLAIN);
       //add image file
       addFromFile(getMMMessage(),getImageFile(),"<1>",IMMConstants.CT_IMAGE_JPEG);
       //set MMEncoder
       setMMEncoder(new MMEncoder());
       getMMEncoder().setMessage(getMMMessage());
       //transaction ID (second parameter) is arbitrary
       setMessage(getMMMessage(),"T135d743a6b7",senderNumber);

        try {
            getMMEncoder().encodeMessage();
            out = getMMEncoder().getMessage();

            setMMSender(new MMSender());
            getMMSender().setMMSCURL("http://mms.metropcs.net:3128/mmsc");
            //'min' of sending device. Required by Metro PCS MMSC.
            getMMSender().addHeader("X-DEVICE-MIN", min);

            setMMResponse(getMMSender().send(out));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          return false;
        }
        return (getMMResponse().getResponseCode()==IMMConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_OK);
   }
```

I am wondering if it is possible to 'tweak' Nokia's code (if this is necessary) such that any device can send a properly constructed MMS request to Metro PCS's MMSC using my 'min' credentials. I have studied the packet flow (via 'WireShark') of what occurs when an MMS is successfully sent from my particular device to other recipients however when I run this same android app. on another device (a non-Metro PCS device), MMS messages fail to send and 'WireShark' is not helpful in explaining why. Can anyone help lead me in the direction of how I might make this work?

**Update**: It may help to add that logcat reports:
`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out`

**Second Update:** I took a look at another post regarding this issue. It is titled *"Android sending image via MMS programatically(Operation timed out)"* but unfortunately there currently is not a definite answer and this question has been live for two months. I will try increasing the read 'timeout' as someone suggested (I doubt this is the cause) but if anyone **DOES** know what the problem might be but simply wishes not to provide a direct answer this is fine. I just need a hint of where to look.

**Third Update:** Now that I think about it, I wonder if the senders IP address (the actual IP address used by the device) constitutes a factor here. Can anyone confirm?

**Fourth Update:** I just took a closer look at the code for 'MMSender.java' (specifically at whats going on with the 'HttpURLConnection' object) and according to its `setReadTimeout(ms)` method, the default value ('0') establishes an infinite wait time anyways and this method is not called anywhere in the code. Just for kicks, however, I manually set this value to 1 minute for both `setConnectionTimeout(ms)` and `setReadTimeout(ms)` and as I suspected, no dice. Same connect timeout issue.
**Final Update:** Sorry. I just realized that I copied this line of code from another posting some time ago:
    `((ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,"enableSUPL");`
and now after looking at this call more closely, I wonder if it is possible that I am supplying incorrect parameter values to `startUsingNetworkFeature()` (at least for the non-Metro PCS device I am trying the application on). I don't want to overkill my 'updates' here for this question but I want you guys (or gals) to be well informed so...; if these parameter values do turn out to be the problem, I will definitely post that fact but this will be my final update. In the mean time, any advice is greatly appreciated.